# Xcode displaying JSON issues

Tags: ios, mysql, json, xcode, ios8

I got my json data from my online server in an array and tried to create objects from each row of json information to then store in an array, this works however the object has content but the summary is always (null). So i can't do anything with the objects.

this is where i try to download data put it into objects and put the objects in an array

```
-(void) retrievecatData
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getcatDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsoncatarray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];



    //categorie array maken
    catArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //loop door jsoncatarray
    for (int i = 0; i < jsoncatarray.count; i++){
        //maak categorie object
        NSString * cID = [[jsoncatarray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSString * cName = [[jsoncatarray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Naam"];

        //categorie object toevoegen aan categoriearray
        [catArray addObject:[[Cat alloc]initWithcatID:cID andcatName:cName]];

    }


    [self.collectionView reloadData];


}
```

this is array when i set a break point

```
catArray    NSMutableArray *    @"1 object" 0x00007fb2cae58d30
[0] Cat *   (null)  0x00007fb2cad59e40
NSObject    NSObject        
catID   NSString *  @"1"    0x00007fb2cae58010
catName NSString *  @"Kleding"  0x00007fb2cae58a00
```

I just really need to get rid of the (null) part after [0] Cat *

Answer (score 0):

Add option to your request and encoding to your data

```
NSData * data = [getcatDataURL dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsoncatarray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```